# Django rendering field not working

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

My model:

```
class preguntas(models.Model):
pregunta = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

My views:

```
opciones = preguntas.objects.all()
return render_to_response(template, {"pregunta": pregunta, "opciones": opciones})
```

Supposedly if in the template I write {{ opciones.pregunta }} it should return the field questions , but it doesnt , any idea ?

If you need more info tell me

Answer (score 1):

You load a queryset `opciones` but don't seem to load anything called `pregunta` before listing it in your context variables. `pregunta` is an attribute of an instance of an individual member of the `opciones` queryset.

Since `opciones` is a queryset, you would need to iterate through it to see each individual item in your template. Your template should look more like:

```
{% for o in opciones %}
{{ o.pregunta }}
{% endfor %}
```

Also, I believe when you use render_to_response you should also add `context_instance=RequestContext(request)` in order for things to work 100% smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're passing in a list of preguntas as opciones. So you need to iterate over the list in order to read the corresponding pregunta.

```
{% for p in opciones %}
    {{ p.pregunta }} <!--do something with each pregunta-->
{% endfor %}
```

EDIT: souldeux beat me to it.

Comment: I'm doing this and for some reason its returning a number and not the string that the field contains

Comment: Is that your full model definition or are there other things going on that you haven't included?